# Test JavaFX ListView item selection

Tags: unit-testing, javafx, javafx-8, junit5

I would like to create a unit test (with JUnit 5) for a controller which consists only of a `ListView`. The use case I want to test is when an item is selected/clicked-on the correct callback is invoked.

In my unit test I am doing the following:

`myController.theListUnderTesting.selectionModel.select(i-th element)`

But the `selectedItemProperty` listener is never invoked. This obviously works without problems when launching and using the application normally.

I've seen there are libraries such as TestFX that aid in testing but I don't like it because it launches the application and simulates the user interaction on screen.

Is there anyway to test such behavior without having to run the application and simulate the interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was:

```
Node nodeToClick = myController.getTheListUnderTesting().getChildrenUnmodifiable()[123];

            MouseEvent mouseEvent =
                    new MouseEvent(
                            MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                            0.0,
                            0.0,
                            0.0,
                            0.0, MouseButton.PRIMARY, 1, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true,
                            new PickResult(nodeToClick, 0.0, 0.0)
                    );

            MouseEvent.fireEvent(nodeToClick, mouseEvent);
```